# R doesn't read in URL from data into Web-Crawler

Tags: r, web-scraping, web-crawler

Hello to all professionals out here,

I have created a csv which consists of cities and the corresponding Tripadvisor_Urls. If I now search for a specific link in my list, for example like here to Munich, the subset function ejects the URL. Now I try to read this URL, which is stored under search_url, using read_html. Unfortunately without success.

The relevant part of my code is the following.

```
search_url <- subset(data, city %in% "München", select = url)
pages <- read_html(search_url)

pages <- pages %>% 
  html_nodes("._15_ydu6b") %>% 
  html_attr('href')
```

When I run search_url I get the following output:

```
https://www.tripadvisor.de/Restaurants-g187323-Berlin.html
```

But when I use the above code and want to execute read_html, the following error occurs:

```
Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : 
  no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
```

I have now spent several hours on it, but unfortunately I have not received a suitable tip anywhere. It would be wonderful if you could help me here.

Comment: The first argument in `read_html` is a string, not a data.frame. We do not know your data.frame structure, but perhaps use `search_url[1,1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the result of `subset()` is a data frame here, although the real result is simply one string. Check this simple example with `mtcars`:

```
# this will be data.frame although the result is one numeric value 21.4
class(subset(mtcars, disp == 258, select = mpg))
# [1] "data.frame"
```

So you probably can use

```
pages <- read_html(as.character(search_url))
```

if you are sure that your subset returns only 1 character value, otherwise

```
pages <- read_html(search_url[1, 1])
```

should work as well for the first result of your subset.

Comment: Thank you so much Petr. It worked with the following command: `pages <- read_html(as.character(search_url[1, 1]))`